# Apache Cordova show HTML source from web service

Tags: android, jquery, rest, cordova

I have a web service which returns the `HTML` code (source) as response. How can I render the response in the Cordova App on Android platform? The response is from a payment gateway transaction web service request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either save the results as HTML or use the URL and then the "Webview" object to show your results. See the tutorials here:

[Cordova Webview](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/webview.html)

Put your response here:
cwv.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

An example is here:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/blob/master/framework/src/org/apache/cordova/CordovaWebView.java

Comment: Could you please provide some more details or example code?

Comment: see the last bit, just run the full example and play till you get the hang of it.

Comment: If you want to see how they work see here, it is simply a window with call to HTML: https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/newWebView.html